# Symmetry error, false center

Tags: sculpting, error, blender-osm

So if u can see the photo, my center at my symmetry was wrong, anybody can help me?[image]

Comment: the center of the symmetry will be your origin, where is the object origin?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment by *moonboots*, the origin of your character might not be in the center of your object. The origin is indicated by the little orange dot in the viewport.
In `Object Mode` you can set the origin. Select `Object` → `Set Origin` → `Origin to Geometry` in the menu of the viewport to center it. This should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments and answers above, you need to set the origin (the orange dot) of your mesh in its centre in order for symmetry to work properly. The easiest method would be the one indicated by *Blunder* (i.e. setting origin to geometry). However, it does not always work as wanted and, therefore, you may want to specify the exact origin of your mesh. I do this by positioning 3D cursor at specific vertex and fixing the origin to 3D cursor position.

- Select the mesh
- Go into edit mode
- Select a vertex along the central line of the mesh
- Press `Shift+S` and swipe to `Cursor to Selected`
- Switch to object mode, select `Object`→`Set Origin`→ `Origin to 3D Cursor`

[image]